# file_get_contents() no such file or directory

Tags: php

So I am using file_get_contents to read in a file, but it keeps telling me that the file is not there.

The call I'm making:

```
file_get_contents("/var/www/dev/includes/cookies/test_cookies.txt").
```

I know the file on the server exists, but yet it still throws a 'no file or directory found'.

Comment: You should put quotes around the path: `file_get_contents("/var/www/dev/includes/cookies/test_cookies.txt")`, but that might be a copy-paste action. Does the web server have read access to the file?

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I forgot quotes when typing the question. They exist in the original call.

Comment: If you're certain it's there, check if every "group" has read rights...

Comment: Does the web user have access to read the file?

Comment: @Plenka, yes the server has read/write access

Comment: try giving absolute path of the txt file.

Comment: @AashuSpk that looks like the absolute path to me.

Comment: @AashuSpk, Dagon is correct, the path given is the absolute path.

Comment: i don't think it's absolute path, if this file is on the server for example,
http://somesite.com/file.txt
then provide that path.

Comment: @Raphioly-San, the group can read/write. Everyone else can read the file.

Comment: @AashuSpk, if I go to the root directory and type cat and pathname, i get the file. It's the absolute path.

Comment: @Blaris try to use the fopen() approach. Otherwise, it may just be that your php environment isn't allowing you to go beyond your website boundaries... I can't help you there, I'm used to 'open' systems ;)

Comment: in which directory this script is saved?

Comment: @AashuSpk, it is saved to /var/www/dev

Comment: then your path should be "includes/cookies/test_cookies.txt" , please try it and let us know.

Comment: @AashuSpk no he has the absolute path, why would changing it to a relative path make it work?

Comment: I believe it is some sort of environmental setup that is creating this bug as it works on STAGE and TEST. I have to put it to the side right now. But will post an answer when I get it fixed.